# Minipage, multiline caption centering

Tags: captions, minipage

No matter what I do, I can't seem to center the bottom line of these minipage captions. Along with the several variations in the code below, I have also tried `\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}`. Advice?

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \minipage{0.14\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{five3}
    \caption*{\scriptsize ($d.d.d.d, c.d.c.d, \newline
                            b.d.d.b.d.d, \newline
                            a.d.a.d.c.b.c.d$) \newline
                            $c=a+b$ \newline
                            $d=c+b$}
  \endminipage\hfill

  \minipage{0.14\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{four3}
    \caption*{\scriptsize ($d.d.d.d, \newline 
                            d.c.c.c, \newline  
                            b.c.b.c.b.d.d, \newline 
                            a.d.a.d.b.c.b.c.d$) \newline 
                            $c=a+b$ \newline 
                            $d=c+b$ \centering}
  \endminipage\hfill
\endminipage
\end{figure}
```

Comment: A [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to work with would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just place the content of the `\caption` in a `tabular` (or `array`, depending on your preference)?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{caption,graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \minipage{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = 100pt]{example-image-a}
    \caption*{\scriptsize $\array{c}(d.d.d.d, c.d.c.d, \\
        b.d.d.b.d.d, \\
        a.d.a.d.c.b.c.d) \\
        c = a+b \\
        d = c+b
      \endarray$}
  \endminipage
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps also `\array{@{}c@{}}...`?

Answer (score 2):

The combination of `\centering` and `\newline` does not give the desired output, as one can see from this simple document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering
First line\newline Second line}
\par\bigskip
\noindent\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering
First line\\ Second line}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So don't use `\newline` inside your caption but `\\` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\captionsetup{justification=centering,font=scriptsize}
\minipage{0.14\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{five3}
\caption*{($d.d.d.d, c.d.c.d,$ \\  $b.d.d.b.d.d,$ \\ $a.d.a.d.c.b.c.d$) \\ $c=a+b$ \\ $d=c+b$}
\endminipage\hfill

\minipage{0.14\textwidth} \centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{four3}
\caption*{($d.d.d.d,$ \\ $d.c.c.c,$ \\  $b.c.b.c.b.d.d,$ \\ $a.d.a.d.b.c.b.c.d$) \\ $c=a+b$ \\ $d=c+b$}
\endminipage\hfill
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need neither `figure` nor `\caption*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo is just for the example
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width = .14\columnwidth]{five3}\\[\abovecaptionskip]
\scriptsize
($d.d.d.d,$\\
$c.d.c.d,$
$b.d.d.b.d.d,$\\
$a.d.a.d.c.b.c.d$)\\
$c=a+b$\\
$d=c+b$
\end{center}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]