# How to center table caption that includes a newline

Tags: tables, line-breaking, captions

My table caption spans more than on line so I added a `\newline` to split the caption at an appropriate position. Now, the two lines are left aligned. How do I center the two lines of the caption?

```
\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{center}
\caption{my caption line one\newline my caption line two}
\begin{tabular}{|r|c|c|c|c|c|}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: best way is to use the `caption` package and define the default caption format as centering

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. There is an offset. The offset has the size of the caption prefix (TableX.X).

Comment: Do not use `\ņewline` but \\ instead since combining `\centering` and `\newline` gives strange results. See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130776/2574

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt \\ is throwing a compiler error for me when used in the caption field.

Answer (score 17):

Package `caption` allows many customizations. Centered caption texts can be achieved by option `justification=centering`.

However, because of the manual line break, the result isn't too pleasing. Therefore I have added an own format using centering inside environment `varwidth` of package `varwidth`. It cuts down the lines to the needed length.

The third table adds `labelsep=newline` to add a first line for the table label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{varwidth}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{%
  % #1: label (e.g. "Table 1")
  % #2: separator (e.g. ": ")
  % #3: caption text
  \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}%
    \centering
    #1#2#3%
  \end{varwidth}%
}
% \captionsetup{format=myformat}% global activation

\begin{document}

  \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \caption{my caption line one\newline my caption line two}
    \begin{tabular}{|r|c|c|c|c|c|}
      \hline
      \verb|\captionsetup{justification=centering}|\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

  \captionsetup{format=myformat}

  \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \caption{my caption line one\newline my caption line two}
    \begin{tabular}{|r|c|c|c|c|c|}
      \hline
      \verb|\captionsetup{format=myformat}|\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

  \captionsetup{labelsep=newline}

  \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \caption{my caption line one\newline my caption line two}
    \begin{tabular}{|r|c|c|c|c|c|}
      \hline
      \verb|\captionsetup{format=myformat, labelsep=newline}|\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Tested with the following versions (`\listfiles`):

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 caption.sty    2013/05/02 v3.3-89 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2013/05/02 v1.6-88 caption3 kernel (AR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
varwidth.sty    2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
 ***********
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. However I couldn't compile it
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \DeclareCaptionFormat 
                                      
l.71 \DeclareCaptionFormat
                          {myformat}{%
?

Comment: @rch: Outdated version? I have added the output of `\listfiles` to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

So I just tried this and it works. If you use `\caption{some text}{then the new line}` it will break the two lines and have them center justified.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Typically `\caption` only takes one mandatory argument (in braces), so `then new line` is not actually part of the caption, and will for example not show up in the list of figures, if you have one of those.

Comment: I strongly believe caption takes only one argument. It might work *by chance*, since your second line is treated as text that is put after the caption

Comment: This answer does not seem to be correct!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newlength{\temp}
\settowidth{\temp}{my caption line xxx }

\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{center}
\caption{\parbox[t]{\temp}{my caption line one\\ my caption line two}}
\begin{tabular}{|r|c|c|c|c|c|}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 
\newline
in between two lines the use of
\\
will do the centering for the 2nd line.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp] \centering%
\begin{threeparttable}

\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{Canadian Pulp and Paper Production and Export \\ 
\small{In Thousand MT (\% World Share)}}%
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc} 
\hline
Year & Production & Export & Production & Export & Production & Export \\ 
\hline
2005 & 25417 & 10612 & 19613 & 15731 & 7769 & 7324 \\
& (14.6) & (24.9) & (5.5) & 13.9 & (20.3) & (41.0)\\  
\hline
\end{tabular}%
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```